# как исправить error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token и error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int k, a;
    double sum=0;
    cin >> k;
    int *n = new int[k];
    for (int i=0; i < k; i++) {
        cin >> n[i];
        for (n[i]; a=1; n[i] > 0; n[i]--) 
        {
            a=a*n[i];
        }
        sum=sum+a;
    }
    cout<<sum;
    return 0;
}
```

выдает

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:13:33: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
         for (n[i]; a=1; n[i] > 0; n[i]--) {
                                 ^
main.cpp:13:41: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
         for (n[i]; a=1; n[i] > 0; n[i]--) {
                                         ^
```

два часа не могу понять, как исправить, помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: В скобках после `for` должно быть три элемента (соответстенно, две `;`). У вас - четыре. Зачем там `n[i]`?

Comment: `for (a=1; n[i] > 0; n[i]--) `

Comment: Что этот вопрос так заминусовали? Написано более-менее коротко и все по делу, а не очередное "сделайте мне задание". Ошибка может и пустяковая, но с таким мутным сообщением от компилятора совсем неудивительно, что новичку сложно разобраться.

Comment: спасибо, что хоть кто-то пожалел
ps стаж программирования на с++ - 3 часа

Comment: @саша: "стаж программирования на с++" - это бывает. Но это ведь не означает, что вы писали код путем слепого ляпания кувалдой по клавиатуре, так? Выписывая этот `for` вы руководствовались какой-то логикой, пусть возможно и неправильной. Так вот, какая логика привела вас к этому `for (n[i]; a=1; n[i] > 0; n[i]--)`? Что вы хотели этим сказать? Что делает одинокое `n[i]`в начале этого `for`?

Answer (score 2):

Надо вместо `;` после `n[i]` поставить `,` (запятую), так как ты перечисляешь параметры, а компилятор твою запись читает по шаблону(счётчик; условие; действие).

Comment: Проще совсем убрать `n[i]; `.

Comment: Проще. Но, если вдруг в дальнейшем автору понадобится несколько параметров-счётчиков, благодаря ответу он будет знать, как это реализовать.